# Hide Kendo date picker based on drop down list selection

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have a Kendo drop down list and a date picker and I'd the datepicker element to be invisible when the drop down selection is 'Not Started'

```html
<div id="view">
  <label for="dateinput">Completed Date</label>
  <input id="completedatepicker" value="" title="monthpicker" />
</div>


<div>
  <label for="dropdown">Status</label>
  <input id="dropdown" />
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // create DatePicker from input HTML element
    $("#duedatepicker").kendoDatePicker();

    $("#completedatepicker").kendoDatePicker();

    $('#dropdown').kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: ['Not Started', 'Completed', 'In Progress']
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // create DatePicker from input HTML element
    $("#duedatepicker").kendoDatePicker();
    $("#completedatepicker").kendoDatePicker();
    $('#dropdown').kendoDropDownList({
      dataSource: ['Not Started', 'Completed', 'In Progress'],
      change:function(e){
        if(e.sender.value() != "Not Started"){
          $("#view").show();
        } else {
          $("#view").hide();
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.117/styles/kendo.default-ocean-blue.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.117/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2023.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="view" style="display:none;">
  <label for="dateinput">Completed Date</label>
  <input id="completedatepicker" value="" title="monthpicker" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="dropdown">Status</label>
  <input id="dropdown" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initially hide the DatePicker container, add a [change event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/events/change) handler and toggle the visibility of the container - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/iNazebuF)